# How can i connect my php code in an existing log in form?

Tags: php, html, arrays

This is my code, I want to get the username just like in the yahoomail.. after you log in your name will appear having a greeting "Hi! or Welcome"

```
session_start();
error_reporting();


if (empty($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
header('location: index_en.htm');
exit;
}
$users =  $_SESSION['user_id'];
if (!$users) { 
header('location: index_en.htm');
exit;
}

echo'<font color="blue"> Hi! </font>'.' '.'('.$_SESSION['user_id'].')';
?>


<?php
echo $login =  $_SESSION['login'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM $tbl_name WHERE user_id='$login' ");
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: ...so have an if statement that sees if you're logged in, and if so, print their name.

Comment: Was $_SESSION['login'] declared? Should it not be $_SESSION['user_id']?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting();

if (empty($_SESSION['user_id']))
{
    header('location: index_en.htm');
    exit;
}
$users =  $_SESSION['user_id'];
if (!$users)
{ 
    header('location: index_en.htm');
    exit;
}

echo $login =  $_SESSION['login'];//this line makes no sense to me
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM $tbl_name WHERE user_id='$login' ");
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);  
echo'<font color="blue"> Hi! </font>'.$rows[0];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

huhm, try this

```
session_start();
$username = $_POST['usernamelog'];
$pass = $_POST['passwordlog'];

$checkexist = $db->query("Select * From users Where username = '$username' and password = '$pass' ") or die('abc');
$obj = $checkexist->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if (isset($_POST['btnlogin'])){
    if($checkexist->rowCount() <= 0){
        echo 'Wrong username or pwd';
    }
    else {
    $name = $obj->username;
    $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
    }
}
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
$alert = $_SESSION['name'];  
$alert = '<p>Hello <a href="#" >'.$_SESSION['name'].'</a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="logout.php"> logout</a></p>';
                        }
 else {
     header("Location: login.php");
 };
```

html

```
<form method="post" action="check-login.php" name="login">
                Username: <input type="text" name="usernamelog" /><br /><br />
                Password: <input type="password" name="passwordlog" /><br /><br />
                <input type="submit" name="btnlogin" value="Log In" />
```